# Cell by cell conditional formatting in Excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have Table1 and Table2 in Excel and would like compare each cell of Table2 with the corresponding cell of Table1 and colour the cell in Table2 grey, iff it is not identical with the corresponding cell in Table1.

I know how to do it for single cells, for instance for cell F8:

=F8<>Table1!F8

How do I, however, proceed to apply these comparisons and actions to each cell of Table2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify correct `Applies to` range and then in formula use first upper left cells of both tables:

[image]

i.e. if tou tables are in sheets `Table1` and `Table2` from cells `F8` to `Z1000`, then in sheet `Table2` open CF dialog and specify in `Applies to` `F8:Z1000` and in `Formula` `=F8<>Table1!F8`. That's all.

Comment: Thx. It took me a while to understand that the Formula-part is somewhat flexible. It does not seem to matter whether I put "=F8<>Table1!F8" there or "=F101<>Table1!F101" as long as the range is set correctly in the Applies-to-section.

Answer (score 0):

You must have both table formatted as table. If you use your formula in one cell after moment whole table will be full. Then you use conditional- formatting

Comment: No offence, but that's not helping.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).